# I want to register domain name for blog, which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

This blog is about career

should it be "careersblog" or "careerblog"

Thank you very much.

Comment: "This blog is about career" is unclear. Your career? Careers as a topic? Answers can only be as precise as your given context until you flesh it out a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with either term given that they relate to a web site; it could be argued that it is a blog about a "career" as a subject, or a blog about various different "careers".

On a practical level I would strongly advise registering both, because you ***know*** that people will make typos. Pick the one which is most appropriate to your content. (Probably "career" if it's advice about how to improve your career in general, "careers" if it's about various specific careers, but it's up to you.) Then have the other one redirect to your chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a domain name, "career" and "careers" are the same.

Anybody visiting your website, whether it's "careerblog.???" or "careersblog.???", will most likely not be influenced by the difference in wording.

Where the difference will really matter will be in selecting the best [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain).

If "careersblog.com" is available to register (it's not, but I'm just saying) and for careerblog you can only get "careerblog.tt" (Trinidad & Tobago), then I would suggest going with "careersblog.com". Unless, of course, you're looking for a country specific TLD.

Always try to secure the .com first. Then, if you want to protect yourself from copycats, [squatters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting) and competitors, buy up all the other extensions (.net, .org., .yourcountrycode).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: There are hundreds more TLD's available right now. ".career" is even proposed itself.

Comment: To protect your brand, I would suggest buying the most popular extensions (.com, .net and .org) and then your country extension if you're outside the USA (e.g., co.uk). Yes, there are hundreds of other domain extensions available. They're not as important as the ones I just mentioned. And in a worse case scenario, you file a lawsuit or a [WIPO complaint](http://www.wipo.int/amc/en/domains/) against whoever infringes on your intellectual property.

Comment: Lawsuit may fail in that someone else may already have a blog or two based on careers? For example: http://www.careersblog.com

Comment: Correct. But I was talking in more general terms. Let's say you built a popular and profitable blog named LamarLatrellCareerBlog.com, and somebody comes around and registers the .net because you didn't, you may still have legal recourse. But we're getting off-topic now ;-) Good luck with your blog. Hope my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: What on earth does this question have to do with English Usage? IMO it does not belong on this site.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: I know where you're coming from, but poor use of language, even in the domain name, can have a pretty important impact on how one's site is perceived. One of the worst examples of this is "Net-informations.com" which I find immediately off-putting because of the obvious mangling of the name. (Though in my opinion my impression was borne out by the content.) Consequently I can understand why someone (particularly someone who is a non-English speaker) would want to avoid that kind of howler and ask for advice.

Comment: @brian because domain name requires using english letters and English is not my first language, so I think this is the place I can find the right answer.